Messages are not ordering correctly in Firebase
I created firebase website using JS and frontend.
Eveything works correctly expect this one thing. My chats are not ordering by date correctly.I want them to order in chronological order, so the older messages are on top.
My JSON snippet
"messages": {
    "-O70WTtDPs8et5-zRVV4": {
      "message": "Hello!",
      "senderId": "UJA4AVrSSdZGOJc0bXYbxOcLOB22",
      "timestamp": 1726602407195
    },
    "-O70WW1AMJk4mJHBZuaY": {
      "message": "Hey",
      "senderId": "nKHb1krQokcFdo5VcDusaaj9TLl1",
      "timestamp": 1726602415953
    },
    "-O70WYXD2x6cNmQJAg2n": {
      "message": "How are you?",
      "senderId": "UJA4AVrSSdZGOJc0bXYbxOcLOB22",
      "timestamp": 1726602426203
    },
    "-O70WbhflR-FBuYtvcNn": {
      "message": "Good, thanks !",
      "senderId": "nKHb1krQokcFdo5VcDusaaj9TLl1",
      "timestamp": 1726602443313
    },
    "-O70X0TNMogcRrGyKYiJ": {
      "message": "Can I exchange X",
      "senderId": "UJA4AVrSSdZGOJc0bXYbxOcLOB22",
      "timestamp": 1726602548834
    },
    "-O70X2GLfa2aKc1KOV-C": {
      "message": "Yep",
      "senderId": "nKHb1krQokcFdo5VcDusaaj9TLl1",
      "timestamp": 1726602556185
    },
    "-O70hzi8OgVY6eRybn3D": {
      "message": "Hallo",
      "senderId": "UJA4AVrSSdZGOJc0bXYbxOcLOB22",
      "timestamp": 1726605687282
    }
  }

This is what i see now:

User1: Hello! (9/17/2024, 10:46:47 PM)
User1: How are you? (9/17/2024, 10:47:06 PM)
User2: Good, thanks ! (9/17/2024, 10:47:23 PM)
User2: Hey (9/17/2024, 10:46:55 PM)

What I want to see:

User2: Hey (9/17/2024, 10:46:55 PM)
User1: Hello! (9/17/2024,10:46:47 PM)
User1: How are you? (9/17/2024, 10:47:06 PM)
User2:    Good, thanks ! (9/17/2024, 10:47:23 PM)

So even though User2 texted first when logged in as User1 I see first mt messages and only then User2 messages
My code
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      const chatId = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("chatId");
      if (!chatId) {
        console.error("Invalid or missing chatId in URL.");
        return;
      }

      // Retrieve messages ordered by timestamp
      const messagesRefForDisplay = firebase
        .database()
        .ref(`chats/${chatId}/messages`)
        .orderByChild("timestamp");
      // Use a regular reference for sending messages
      const messagesRefForSending = firebase
        .database()
        .ref(`chats/${chatId}/messages`);

      // Function to get username from user ID
      function getUsername(userId, callback) {
        const userRef = firebase.database().ref(`users/${userId}`);
        userRef.once("value", (snapshot) => {
          const userData = snapshot.val();
          callback(userData.username);
        });
      }
      function formatTimestamp(timestamp) {
        const date = new Date(timestamp);
        return date.toLocaleString(); // Customize the format if needed
      }

      // Load messages ordered by timestamp
      messagesRefForDisplay.on("child_added", (snapshot) => {
        const message = snapshot.val();
        getUsername(message.senderId, (username) => {
          const messageElement = document.createElement("div");
          messageElement.classList.add("message");
          const formattedTimestamp = formatTimestamp(message.timestamp);

          messageElement.innerHTML = `<span class="sender">${username}:</span> ${message.message} <span class="timestamp">(${formattedTimestamp})</span>`;
          document.getElementById("messages").appendChild(messageElement);

          // Auto scroll to the bottom after a new message is added
          document.getElementById("messages").scrollTop =
            document.getElementById("messages").scrollHeight;
        });
      });

      // Send message
      document.getElementById("sendMessage").addEventListener("click", () => {
        const messageInput = document.getElementById("messageInput");
        const messageText = messageInput.value.trim();
        if (messageText) {
          // Use the unfiltered messagesRef for sending
          messagesRefForSending
            .push({
              message: messageText,
              senderId: user.uid, // Use user.uid here
              timestamp: Date.now(),
            })
            .then(() => {
              console.log("Message sent successfully");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error("Error sending message:", error);
            });
          messageInput.value = ""; // Clear the input
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log("User is not logged in.");
    }
  });
});


Can you explain the ordering criteria? Your desired result isn't ordered by time, what is it?

I have a feeling you expect the message to be chronilogically ordered because of this code .orderByChild("timestamp"). In that case can you show a snippet of the JSON under chats/${chatId}/messages in your database (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this JSON by clicking Export JSON in the Firebase web console.

Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Hi! I added the JSON snippet and explained a little bit better what is my problem. I can totally say that it is something to do with the logic of my code. @AlexMamo

Hi! I added the JSON snippet and explained a little bit better what is my problem. I can totally say that it is something to do with the logic of my code. @FrankvanPuffelen

@Barmar I think with the new snippet it is more clear. I want the messages to order by time, but now it seems it is ordered first messages of loggedin user and then user2

In "What I want to see" they're not ordered by time, that's why I'm confused. The first message is 8 seconds after the second message.

I think you might be experiencing a race condition due to the loading of the user names. A simple fix is to add the element to the HTML straight away, before you start loading the user name:
// Load messages ordered by timestamp
messagesRefForDisplay.on("child_added", (snapshot) => {
  const message = snapshot.val();
  const messageElement = document.createElement("div");
  messageElement.classList.add("message");
  document.getElementById("messages").appendChild(messageElement);
  getUsername(message.senderId, (username) => {
    const formattedTimestamp = formatTimestamp(message.timestamp);

    messageElement.innerHTML = `<span class="sender">${username}:</span> ${message.message} <span class="timestamp">(${formattedTimestamp})</span>`;

    // Auto scroll to the bottom after a new message is added
    document.getElementById("messages").scrollTop =
      document.getElementById("messages").scrollHeight;
  });
});

